# MAPI address book provider: contact card pop-up

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-2016

How to add 'PR_TITLE', 'PR_COMPANY_NAME' and 'contact picture' to pop-up window of message recipient which is placed in address row in message compose?

I use custom MAPI Address Book Provider to add recipient to address row.

Answer (score 0):

The popup card is not customizable.

Comment: ОК, but I just need to fill it with data. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think you can.